# cant get my wcf web.config working

Tags: wcf, session, web-config

im a noob with wcf and i need some help.

To be honest i don't understand much about the web.config file and its a lot to take in.

I have a Service.svc.cs and a interface for it IService.cs i want to make a login system where a user can login from a client.

```
//Service Contract
[ServiceContract]
public class ItheService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Login(string email, string password);
}

//interface
public class TheService : ItheService
{
    public string Login(string email, string password)
    {
        //some code
        return "";
    }
}
```

Iv read a lot of pages and tried a few different web.config variations and got errors about the contract requiring session.

I know that i need behavior and service settings but i don't know what to use.

Could someone explain what i need to put into the web.config file?

I originally had this web.config but i know its wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="httpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="TheService.theService">
        <endpoint address=""
                     behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior"
                     binding="webHttpBinding"
                     contract="TheService.ItheService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Share your config file .

Comment: your config is typically contains as ABC of your service. A- Address, b-Binding, C-Contract. Typically the configuration to run yout service should be very simple. If you can post the config, we will be able to help you

Comment: What are you using as a client?

Comment: i want to connect with multiple types of clients. C# winform and android for example.

Comment: Post the error that you are getting

Comment: I've been able to get your code working.  How are you hosting your service?  I'm using IISExpress and .Net4